# Re-prompt if input is less than or equal to 0

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a function which asks for input from the user which will be parsed to an int and that will be used to create a pyramid.

I know I have to use a loop of some kind and I have tried a do/while loop but I don't seem to understand it. I can't declare n above the Console.Write outside the do/while and if I have it below inside of the do/while, the while condition wont accept it because it's out of the scope. It would seem so simple to say, do(ask for input and assign to n) while(n <=0), but I can't do that.

I also had an idea I tried which was to run the function within itself as long as n was <=0 but that runs the function infinitely. Not sure if I'm on the right track but I feel lost right now.

```
    static void Pyramid()
    {
        Console.Write("Choose a pyramid height: ");
        int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < i + 2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("#"); 
            }

            Console.Write("  ");

            for (int j = 0; j < i + 2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("#");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should works:

```
int n;
do
{
  Console.Write("Choose a pyramid height: ");
  n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
  if ( n <= 0) Console.WriteLine("Value must be greater than 0.");
}
while ( n <= 0 );
```

Comment: +1 , just one suggestion: I'd add an option to cancel the program without drawing the pyramid. (But that's "nice to have".)

Comment: You can always exit a console app by pressing Ctrl+C, @Fildor.

Comment: @CodeCaster That's true. But feels a little bit "ungraceful". Maybe it's a matter of taste, but I like to have a "... or 'X' to exit."

Answer (score 0):

Just use an infinite while loop, and `continue` if the number is invalid:

```
static void Pyramid()
{
    while(true)
    {
        Console.Write("Choose a pyramid height: ");
        int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (n <= 0)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("That's an invalid number");
            continue;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n - 1 - i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < i + 2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("#"); 
            }

            Console.Write("  ");

            for (int j = 0; j < i + 2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("#");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not quite intuitive to simply repeat the question. Wouldn't you want to print an error? Also, as the now-removed comment stated, where'd the `i` loop go? And while we're at it, don't use `Int.Parse()` for user input, use `TryParse()`.

Comment: _"That's an invalid number"_ - my UX-Expert here would tear me a new one for this. Telling the user the allowed range is in my view a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Let's *extract method*. We should implement **2** checks:

1. If input is an *integer* value at all (e.g. `"bla-bla-bla"` is not an integer)
2. If input is a *valid* integer (we don't accept `-123`)

Code:

```
public static int ReadInteger(string prompt, 
                              Func<int, bool> validation = null, 
                              string validationMessage = null) {
  int result;

  while (true) {   
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prompt))
      Console.WriteLine(prompt);

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!int.TryParse(input, out result)) 
      Console.WriteLine("Sorry, your input is not a valid integer value. Please, try again."); 
    else if (validation != null && !validation(result)) 
      Console.WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage)
        ? "Sorry the value is invalid. Please, try again"
        : validationMessage);
    else
      return result;
   }
}
```

then you can easily use it:

```
int n = ReadInteger(
  "Choose a pyramid height:",
   (value) => value > 0,
  "Pyramid height must be positive. Please, try again.");

//TODO: your code here to draw the pyramid of height "n"
```

please, note, that you can easily restrict the upper bound as well (a pyramid of height `1000000000` will hang the computer):

```
int n = ReadInteger(
  "Choose a pyramid height:",
   (value) => value > 0 && value <= 100,
  "Pyramid height must be in [1..100] range. Please, try again.");
```